# Understanding the octet rule

Tags: organic-chemistry

I just started selfstudy with an organic chemistry textbook and I'm not quite getting the motivation behind the octet rule.

Per Bruice's textbook, the octet rule reads

> an atom is most
>   stable if its outer shell is either filled or contains eight electrons and it has no electrons
>   of higher energy

Why are atoms with a filled valence shell most stable?

What is the special case with 8 electrons? I understand that nobles gasses have full valence shells, but why aren't there noble gasses with filled valence s- d- or -f valence shells --- without higher subshells being filled?

Comment: There's already dozens of posts about that and this looks like one of broadests.

Comment: Its a quantum effect. E.G. Pauli exclusion principle has electrons (fermions) in pairs, and there is room for 1 pair in an s orbital, 3 in a p orbital (5 in d and 7 in f... notice odd numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Atoms surrounded by 8 electrons look like noble gases (elements from the last column). And noble gases are particular stable, since they are very reluctant to make bonds with any other atom. And when they accept to make a molecule with some other atom, this molecule is highly unstable, and is decomposed at the next opportunity, sometimes with explosion.

The goal of the octet rule is to explain why Na reacts so violently with many other substances like Chlorine to make NaCl for example, which produces a huge amount of heat. The same for C burning in O2 to make CO2. The flame of C produces  a lot of heat. The octet rule explain why NaCl and CO2 are stable : they don't react so often, and when they do react, the reaction does not liberate much heat.